# Проблема в реализации функции: зеркальные буквы

Tags: php, массивы, функции

Всем доброго дня, пытаюсь реализовать интересную функцию которая будет менять местами буквы к примеру A будет Z, Z будет A, B будет Y и тд и тп. И с помощью этой функции можно будет создавать слова которые будут выводиться в соответствующем порядке то есть к примеру AFF GZIT = ZOO PARK. Пытаюсь понять как правильно это сделать, нужно ли каждую букву занести в ассоциативный массив и с помощью array_reverse их выводить в обратном порядке, и само создание слова будет идти через цикл for or foreach?

Код:

```
function mirrorLetter($certainLetter)
{

     $certainArray1 = [ 'A' => 'Z', 'B' => 'Y', 'C' => 'X', 'D' => 'W',
                    'E' => 'V', 'F' => 'O', 'G' => 'P', 'H' => 'Q',
                    'I' => 'R', 'J' => 'S', 'K' => 'T', 'L' => 'U',
                    'M' => 'N'];


    $certainArray2 = [ 'Z' => 'A', 'Y' => 'B', 'X' => 'C', 'W' => 'D',
                      'V' => 'E', 'O' => 'F', 'P' => 'G', 'Q' => 'H',
                      'R' => 'I', 'S' => 'J', 'T' => 'K', 'U' => 'L',
                      'N' => 'M'];
     
     

     $certainArray1 = array_reverse($certainArray1);
     
     $certainArray2 = array_reverse($certainArray2);

    return $certainArray1[$certainLetter];


}

echo mirrorLetter('A');
```

Comment: Этот код работает?

Comment: К сожалению именно этот код не работает как надо так как это часть функции, здесь я хотел показать что пока есть на данном моменте. Если говорить конкретно за этот код то он просто будет выводить одну букву и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пусть уж для коллекции будет

```
function mirror($str){
    $alphabet = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    $xchange = array_combine($alphabet, array_reverse($alphabet));
    
    
    return join(array_map(function($l) use ($xchange){ 
                    return $xchange[$l]; 
               }, str_split($str) ));
};
```

и еще вариант через замену

```
function mirror($str){
    $alphabet = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    $xchange =  str_split("ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA");
            
    return strtolower(str_replace($alphabet, $xchange, $str));
};
```

оба, очевидно, работают для строки в нижнем регистре

Comment: Ого даже не ожидал такой масштабной реакции от комьюнити, я думаю это не то что для колекции а будет для всех полезно, кстати да насчет нижнего регистра интересно так как я думал пока только за верхние. Спасибо большое !

Comment: @Yurii оно работает для одного регистра не важно какого именно. второй по крайней мере. Первый то расширить можно.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого в PHP есть готовая функция [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php)!

Пример: [ideone](https://ideone.com/G5VVqS)

```
<?php

$replaceTable = [ 
    'A' => 'Z', 
    'B' => 'Y', 
    'C' => 'X', 
    'D' => 'W',
    'E' => 'V', 
    'F' => 'O', 
    'G' => 'P', 
    'H' => 'Q',
    'I' => 'R', 
    'J' => 'S', 
    'K' => 'T', 
    'L' => 'U',
    'M' => 'N',
    'N' => 'M', 
    'O' => 'L', 
    'P' => 'K', 
    'Q' => 'J',
    'R' => 'I', 
    'S' => 'H', 
    'T' => 'G', 
    'U' => 'F',
    'V' => 'E', 
    'W' => 'D', 
    'X' => 'C', 
    'Y' => 'B',
    'Z' => 'A'
];

$string = "HelloWorld";

echo strtr(strtoupper($string), $replaceTable);
```

Comment: вот блин ) помнил же что было что-то такое, но сгородил огород с str_replace

Answer (score 1):

```
$lit = [ 
    'A' => 'Z', 
    'B' => 'Y', 
    'C' => 'X', 
    'D' => 'W',
    'E' => 'V', 
    'F' => 'O', 
    'G' => 'P', 
    'H' => 'Q',
    'I' => 'R', 
    'J' => 'S', 
    'K' => 'T', 
    'L' => 'U',
    'M' => 'N'
];

function code($world, $lit)
{
    $ret = '';
    $str = str_split($world);

    foreach($str as $val)
        $ret .= $lit[$val];

    return $ret;
}

function decode($world, $lit) 
{
    $ret = '';
    $str = str_split($world);

    foreach($str as $val)
        $ret .= array_search($val, $lit);

    return $ret;
}

$code = code('ADAM', $lit);

echo $code . '<br>';
echo decode($code, $lit);
```

Comment: хммм интересно продуманно, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTICE**: тут отсутсвуют некоторые проверки, например слово и букву надо привести к единому регистру, прежде чем сравнивать.

Суть:

- Делаем просто массив алфавита.
- Разбиваем исходную строку на символы
- Пробегаемся по массиву символов и находим его индекс
- Если он в середине алфавита, то берем из алфавита его индекс
- В ином случае берём индекс зеркального элемнета

---

```
function getMirrorredString($string) {
    $alphabet = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
    
    $mirroredString = '';
    $splittedString = str_split($string);
    
    $alphabetCount = count($alphabet);
    $alphabetMiddle = floor($alphabetCount - 1 / 2);

    foreach($splittedString as $char)  {
        $charIndex = array_search($char, $alphabet, true);
        $mirroredString .= $charIndex === $alphabetMiddle ? $alphabet[$charIndex] :  $alphabet[$alphabetCount - $charIndex - 1];
    }
    
    return $mirroredString;
}


echo getMirrorredString('ABCZYX');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за четкое объяснение в коде

Answer (score 1):

```
function mirrorLetter($letter)
{
    $code_letter   = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'Z', 'Y', 'X', 'W', 'V', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'N', ' '];
    $decode_letter = [ 'Z', 'Y', 'X', 'W', 'V', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'N', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', ' '];

    for ($i=0; $i<count($code_letter); $i++){
        if ($letter == $code_letter[$i]){
            return $decode_letter[$i];
        }
    }
}


function mirrorWord($word)
{
    foreach (str_split($word) as $letter){
        $mirrorWord .= mirrorLetter($letter);
    }
    return $mirrorWord;
}


echo mirrorWord('AFF GZIT');
```

Comment: Хмммм интересный вариант, спасибо большое